# Images not populating when using Unsplash API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am learning how to use fetch APIs and I can't seem to figure out why only 1 image is showing up when using the Unsplash API. I think it has something to do with map, but I'm not sure. Any help our guidance is appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  console.log(searchTerm);

  fetch(
    `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=e72d3972ba3ff93da57a4c0be4f0b7323346c136b73794e2a01226216076655b&query=${searchTerm}`
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.results);
      let searchResults = data.results
        .map(searchResults => {
          return (document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<img src="${
            searchResults.urls.small
          }">`);
        })
        .join("");
    });
});
```

Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq918mok29

The default 10 images should appear but only 1 shows up. How can I map through the images and show them on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the element's content in each map iteration, so you only see the last one. Use map to build the markup, then drop it into the document.

Something like this:

```
.then(data => {
  let imagesMarkup = '';

  data.results
    .map(searchResults => {
      return (imagesMarkup += `<img src="${searchResults.urls.small}">`);
    }); // note that the join was removed here

    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = imagesMarkup;
});
```

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/145ozvjoz7)**

Comment: YOU DID IT! It worked! I removed the join. Thank you so so so much for your help!